# MySQL invert a column with single query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to invert a boolean column with just one query?

Comment: boolean makes more sense than binary. I just spent the last 5 minutes looking into REVERSE() to see if it would work in a binary string, and wondering why you'd want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET columname = !columname
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT IF (MyBoolean, 0, 1) FROM MyTable;
```

OR

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyBoolean = IF (MyBoolean, 0, 1);
```